Advice needed on devcontainer standards
We are working on using devcontainers across multiple repositories that are interdependent (legacy projects we're trying to enhance for better local development).
Devcontainers seem like an excellent solution, and we've managed to get a few working. However, we are seeking advice on best practices, as the available documentation doesn't seem to cover standards or shared experiences comprehensively.
Here are a few questions we have:

Cloning vs. Mounting Code: Is it better to clone the repository into the container or mount the local code into the container? Mounting seems preferable despite the performance hit.
Using Existing Dockerfiles: All our repositories have existing Dockerfiles. Should we use these Dockerfiles as the base for the devcontainer, or should we create new Dockerfiles in the .devcontainer folder, which feels redundant? However if we were to create new repositories, creating a new Dockerfile in the .devcontainer folder seems logical.
Pulling Production Images: We've considered pulling tagged builds of our 'production' images from Docker Hub as the devcontainer base (not 'latest' to avoid continuous pulls). Our production Dockerfiles contain ARM-specific dependencies that we can't build locally, and this approach addresses that issue. Is this a good practice?

Apologies for the basic questions – we've only been exploring this for a week. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!



Cloning vs. Mounting Code: Is it better to clone the repository into the container or mount the local code into the container? Mounting seems preferable despite the performance hit.


I feel it is better to mount it. Performance may be reduced, but local development will be more seamless and therefore more efficient.


Using Existing Dockerfiles: All our repositories have existing Dockerfiles. Should we use these Dockerfiles as the base for the devcontainer, or should we create new Dockerfiles in the .devcontainer folder, which feels redundant? However if we were to create new repositories, creating a new Dockerfile in the .devcontainer folder seems logical.


I felt it was better to create a new Dockerfile under .devcontainer if possible. devcontainer is for development purposes only. For this reason, I feel that it is better to confine development-specific settings to devcontainer.
